# C# LINQ Group by with the the same amount of items in each group

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I cannot figure out how to group items in a correct way like this. For instance we have a list of dates and teams like this:

| Date | Teams | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | Team1 | 10 |
| 1/1/2021 | Team2 | 10 |
| 1/1/2021 | Team3 | 10 |
| 1/2/2021 | Team1 | 20 |
| 1/2/2021 | Team2 | 20 |
| 1/3/2021 | Team3 | 30 |

I want it to be like this:

| Date | Teams | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | Team1 | 10 |
| 1/1/2021 | Team2 | 10 |
| 1/1/2021 | Team3 | 10 |
| 1/2/2021 | Team1 | 20 |
| 1/2/2021 | Team2 | 20 |
| 1/2/2021 | Team3 | 0 |
| 1/3/2021 | Team1 | 0 |
| 1/3/2021 | Team2 | 0 |
| 1/3/2021 | Team3 | 30 |

Comment: Please show your class structure, and your attempt. Please also include your requirements for grouping (like how do we know which value to choose... or do we sum them?)

Comment: That looks like a order by date, teams

Comment: @Tarik But it's not. It seems to be generating extra data. It seems like OP wants to "fill in" the gaps with 0 values. That's not grouping at all, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: what you need is left join with teams and if there is no matching record in the transaction table then return 0. I assume you have Teams, DateRange and Transaction tables

Comment: @Llama, you are right. maybe not dates table. I assume it is a date range. nevertheless OP should have more details about his class structure and use case

Comment: @Llama thanks for extra editing of my question. About the question, Yeah I think its something like grouping + generating extra data. Dont know exactly how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#:

```cs
public class DataEntry
{
    public string Date;
    public string Teams;
    public int Value;
}

public static IEnumerable<DataEntry> GetData()
{
    var data = new List<DataEntry>()
    {
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/1/2021", Teams = "Team1", Value = 10 },
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/1/2021", Teams = "Team2", Value = 10 },
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/1/2021", Teams = "Team3", Value = 10 },
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/2/2021", Teams = "Team1", Value = 20 },
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/2/2021", Teams = "Team2", Value = 20 },
        new DataEntry() { Date = "1/3/2021", Teams = "Team3", Value = 30 },
    };

    var dates = data.Select(d => d.Date).Distinct().OrderBy(d => d);
    var teams = data.Select(d => d.Teams).Distinct().OrderBy(d => d);

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        foreach (var team in teams)
        {
            yield return new DataEntry()
            {
                Date = date,
                Teams = team,
                Value = data.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Date == date && d.Teams == team)?.Value ?? 0
            };
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var d in GetData()) Console.WriteLine($"{d.Date} {d.Teams} {d.Value}");
}
```

Assuming you have it in a database, it may be easier to do it there

```sql
SELECT t.Date, d.Teams, IsNull(tt.Value, 0) as Value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM #Table) t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Teams FROM #Table) d
  LEFT JOIN #Table tt
    ON t.Date = tt.Date
    AND d.Teams = tt.Teams
ORDER BY t.Date, d.Teams
```

Comment: This works but is very inefficient, because you’re searching the entire dataset for each date-team pair. (You’re also recreating the list of teams for each date, which is inefficient, but easily fixed.)

Comment: One other minor issue with this is that you should parse the date strings before sorting them, so they end up in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```cs
var data = new[]
{
    new { Date = "1/1/2021", Team = "Team1", Value = 10 },
    new { Date = "1/1/2021", Team = "Team2", Value = 10 },
    new { Date = "1/1/2021", Team = "Team3", Value = 10 },
    new { Date = "1/2/2021", Team = "Team1", Value = 20 },
    new { Date = "1/2/2021", Team = "Team2", Value = 20 },
    new { Date = "1/3/2021", Team = "Team3", Value = 30 }
};
```

Then this will produce the table you want:

```cs
var teams = data.Select(rec => rec.Team).Distinct().OrderBy(team => team).ToArray();
var groupings = data.GroupBy(rec => DateTime.Parse(rec.Date));
var table = groupings.OrderBy(grouping => grouping.Key).SelectMany(grouping =>
    {
        var dict = grouping.ToDictionary(rec => rec.Team, rec => rec.Value);
        return teams.Select(team =>
            {
                dict.TryGetValue(team, out int value);
                return new { Date = grouping.Key, Team = team, Value = value };
            });
    });
```

The first statement gives you all the teams in alphabetical order. The second statement groups the records by date. The third statement walks through each date in order, looking up the value for each team on that date (using 0 if there is none).

You can test it like this:

```cs
foreach (var row in table)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Output is:

```
{ Date = 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team1, Value = 10 }
{ Date = 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team2, Value = 10 }
{ Date = 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team3, Value = 10 }
{ Date = 1/2/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team1, Value = 20 }
{ Date = 1/2/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team2, Value = 20 }
{ Date = 1/2/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team3, Value = 0 }
{ Date = 1/3/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team1, Value = 0 }
{ Date = 1/3/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team2, Value = 0 }
{ Date = 1/3/2021 12:00:00 AM, Team = Team3, Value = 30 }
```